# clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

First I have two divs `box1` and `box2` and i have these checkbox(s) which eventually it does stuff. One if these "stuff". is blinking. so I made a function called `blink` where it makes the div sort of blinking.

I passed it through `setInterval` so it would blink until I tell it otherwise. (I tell it to stop blinking with checkbox input)

now to break the Interval I used `clearInterval`. but when I do that I won't stop. it does nothing or I am getting it wrong.

The idea here. when the page start, `#box1` will be already blinking. When checkbox `#stopBlink` is checked. `box2` should start blinking and `box1` should stop. when `#stopBlink` is unchecked `box1` should start blinking and box2 should stops.

Script:

```
    function blink(text) {
        $(text).fadeTo(400, 0.3).fadeTo(900, 1.0);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        box1_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box1")}, 0);

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if($("#stopBlink").is(':checked'))
            {
                clearInterval(box1_id);
                box2_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box2")}, 0);
            }else{
                clearInterval(box2_id);
                box1_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box1")}, 0);
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="DoSomethingElse"> Do Something Else
<input type="checkbox" id="stopBlink"> Stop the Blinking
<div id="box1">BLINKING</div>
<div id="box2">NOT BLINKING</div>
```

Comment: You haven't got an interval set as `box_id`  also why clear box2 before box1 is set

Comment: Shouldn't be `clearInterval(box_id1);` note the `1`?

Comment: also keep in mind box1_id, box2_id are globals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below addresses the code/logic aspects of the question - for your *actual* problem of blinking elements, you're better off using [JAG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006689/791010) and use the CSS that modern browsers allow.

---

There are two issues in the code you've posted.  Firstly, you're initially trying to clear a non-existent interval:

```
clearInterval(box_id);
```

resulting in this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: box_id is not defined

If you fix that, and use:

```
clearInterval(box1_id)
```

It does correctly clear the interval and start the flashing of the 2nd div.  However, we then see the second issue.

Your intervals are all configured to use a 0ms timeout, so as soon as the page loads, you're generating hundreds of calls to `blink`, as fast as the browser can call it.  This means when you click the checkbox, while the interval is cleared, jQuery has already queued up lots of animations, and the first div continues to blink while the second one then starts.

The quickest solution is to just set the intervals to have the same timeout as the animation times:

```js
function blink(text) {
        $(text).fadeTo(400, 0.3).fadeTo(900, 1.0);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        box1_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box1")}, 1300);

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if($("#stopBlink").is(':checked'))
            {
                clearInterval(box1_id);
                box2_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box2")}, 1300);
            }else{
                clearInterval(box2_id);
                box1_id = setInterval(function(){blink("#box1")}, 1300);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="DoSomethingElse"> Do Something Else
<input type="checkbox" id="stopBlink"> Stop the Blinking
<div id="box1">BLINKING</div>
<div id="box2">NOT BLINKING</div>
```

This does result in an initial delay before they start blinking though, so if you want to keep it that they start blinking immediately, you might be better off refactoring slightly to have the blink function call itself:

```js
var timeout;

function blink(text) {
  $(text).fadeTo(400, 0.3).fadeTo(900, 1.0);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    blink(text);
  }, 1300);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  blink("#box1");

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if ($("#stopBlink").is(':checked')) {
      blink("#box2")
    } else {
      blink("#box1")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="DoSomethingElse">Do Something Else
<input type="checkbox" id="stopBlink">Stop the Blinking
<div id="box1">BLINKING</div>
<div id="box2">NOT BLINKING</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, but no love for rAF?

Comment: @JaredSmith Not really appropriate here - this is just a simple timeout to kick off the jQuery animation methods, which hopefully _do_ use it.

Comment: @JaredSmith what is rAF?

Comment: @AbdullahSalma `requestAnimationFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @JamesThorpe the second part is the best, used and greatly working.

Comment: @AbdullahSalma even still, it was more addressed at your logic problems - for the actual underlying issue, the other answer using CSS animations is the way to do it

Comment: @JamesThorpe you code worked smoother than the css., when i check then uncheck quickly the breaking blink is visiable in css, not in your code.

Answer (score 3):

change `setInterval` time to match with total `fade` time

which is `400 + 900 = 1300`

**OR**

you can do same with CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#stopBlink").change(function() {
     $("#box1, #box2").toggleClass('blink');
   });
 });
```

```css
.blink { animation: blink 600ms infinite alternate; }

@keyframes blink {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="DoSomethingElse">Do Something Else
<input type="checkbox" id="stopBlink">Stop the Blinking
<div id="box1" class="blink">BLINKING</div>
<div id="box2">NOT BLINKING</div>
```

Comment: Upvote from me - I was too focused on the code issues and forgot about using CSS for this sort of thing :)